# set batch variable from WSH script

Tags: batch-file, jscript

I am trying to run a batch file that gets a variable from WSH script.
When I run the script I get the correct output but I can't seem to set it to a variable

```
@if (@codesection == @batch) @then


cscript //nologo //e:JScript "%~f0"

set getclip=cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%f~0"

echo "%getclip%"
pause


goto :EOF
@end

WSH.Echo(WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile').parentWindow.clipboardData.getData('text'));
```

the second line echos the clipboard but not the getclip variable

Answer (score 1):

You have a small error in this part: `//e:jscript "%f~0"`

In order to get the output of a command, you need to use the `for /F` command.

Also, a variable can only store *one line*. If you want to get several lines, you need to use an *array*:

```
@if (@codesection == @batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cscript //nologo //e:JScript "%~f0"

ECHO ===============

set "line=0"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo //e:JScript "%~f0"') do (
   set /A line+=1
   set "getclip[!line!]=%%a"
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%line%) do echo !getclip[%%i]!
pause

goto :EOF

@end

WSH.Echo(WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile').parentWindow.clipboardData.getData('text'));
```

Comment: Thank you for setting me on the right path -- I got it with for /f %%i in ('cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~f0"') do set RESULT=%%i

Comment: Yes, it works, but this way you just get the _first word_ of the _last_ line...